# Transfer file via Putty

Tags: putty

I tried Hyperterminal for transferring the data from a linux based
black box device to the pc by using the command lsz.

Now i would like to use PUTTY. How can I set the destination for receiving file/data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an scp client. Putty is not one. You can use WinSCP or PSCP.